# Intellij asking me to add every single maven dependency as project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I wanted to set up my test project so that I could debug into the 3rd party library called "undertow". So I added it as a module of my test project. But then when I try to run my test project, it errors out with messages like "xnio class definition not found". Xnio is a maven dependency of undertow, so shouldnt intellij resolve that automatically? I dont get it.
Then when I added xnio as a module, I get the same error about a logging library.

Surely I'm not supposed to add every single maven dependency as a source module to my test project just so it runs again?

[image]

As you can see, I added the xnio from git as maven module dependency but now it complains about some jboss logger even though xnio itself already has these dependencies.
What kind of setting do I have to take to make intellij auto resolve 3rd party dependencies?

**EDIT**: Oh and this seems to be a runtime issue only, because it compiles fine. Very weird.

Comment: you should post your run configuration as well. There isn't much to go on in the question.

Comment: what configuration do you mean? the launch configuration?

Comment: intellij is useless, seems like it has no such feature as m2eclipse, I still have to do mvn install, then add the deps manually to my pom.xml. But now I have another problem, the undertow project tree is weirdly yellow and has no sources. And everytime I delete it it gets added to global "maven ignored files" in the intellij settings.

Comment: ok apparently the yellow highlighting was because I added it as a library as well as a module, which makes it go "uh no there are no source files". Therefore the only problem seems to have been me not updating the pom manually.